# php echo inside a onclick event doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, php

I got this basic music player, when I click an image music starts, when I click it again music stops, and so on.
When I do this in HTML everything work properly.

```
<script>
    function StartOrStop(audioFile) {
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        if (!audie.src || audie.src !== audioFile) audie.src = audioFile;
        console.log(audie.paused);
        if (audie.paused == false) {
            console.log('pause');
            audie.pause();
        } else {
            console.log('play');
            audie.play();
        }
    }
</script>


<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="400" height="400" onclick="StartOrStop('myMP3.mp3')"> 
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
```

but when i try to connect this to my Database I should simply replace `'myMP3.mp3'` with `'<?php echo $trackA; ?>'`. When I do this and I click for the first time I hear my song, but, when i try to pause the song, the song start from the beginning, it's like the player refresh.

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="400" height="400" onclick="StartOrStop('folder/subfolder/<?php echo $trackA; ?>')">
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to activate `controls` in the audio tag just to understand what's going on, tha controls work properly but when I click the image the song start from the beginning insted of stop it.

I tried also to insert a `var song` in the script but same resoult.

In the console in HTML everything works, but in php I only get `true` and `play`.

what can it be? any ideas?

---

I found this solution and seems work to me. 
in the HTML i add the src to my audio tag insted of take the src from the image

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="400" height="400" onclick="StartOrStop()">
<audio src="admin/files/<?php echo $trackA; ?>" id="myAudio"></audio>
```

and then i edit the js

```
<script>
    function StartOrStop() {
        var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");

        console.log(audie.paused);
        if (audie.paused == false) {
            console.log('pause');
            audie.pause();
        } else {
            console.log('play');
            audie.play();
        }
    }
</script>
```

now, i don't know why it's work!

Comment: PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side. You will have to use AJAX to get something from PHP.

Comment: Does it work when you use the controls of the `audio` tag itself? `<audio controls id='myAudio'>`

Comment: @RST yes. it works correctly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ok, i'll take a look a this. I'm not familiar with the AJAX.

Comment: The song seems to load correctly why would you change to AJAX?

Comment: @RST I know it load it, I don't understand why it's reload it when I press pause. maybe JayBalnchard it's right.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how do I insert AJAX function in this? I've no idea where to start